# change transaction type inside apm elastic opentelemetry

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, open-telemetry

I'm using elastic with open telemetry, and when I try to trace the hosted service (via manual instrumentation), the transaction type appears unknown; how can I add my custom transaction type for.net?

[image: 1]

I'm trying to change the activity display name, but it does not work.

[image: 2]

Does anyone have a sample of how can I change the transaction type?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it there are three transaction types:

- request
- messaging
- unknown

The following specification describes how the transaction type gets determined: https://github.com/elastic/apm/blob/main/specs/agents/tracing-api-otel.md#transaction-type

There is also an implementation example here: https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-dotnet/blob/main/src/Elastic.Apm/OpenTelemetry/ElasticActivityListener.cs#L199

The following snippet shows examples for each transaction type. However, I could not get the `messaging` type to work. It still gets the type `unknown`.

```ml
// request
use activity = activitySource.StartActivity("aaa", ActivityKind.Server)
activity.AddTag("rpc.system", "whatever")

// messaging
use activity = activitySource.StartActivity("bbb", ActivityKind.Consumer)
activity.AddTag("messaging.system", "whatever")

// unknown
use activity = activitySource.StartActivity("ccc", ActivityKind.Internal)
```

I am not aware of custom types.